# Dungeon Generation Methods

Tags: java, algorithm, random, generator

I've been researching a good dungeon algorithm, but I've come into several problems. I'm trying to make a mix between *Realm of the Mad God* and a dungeon crawler. My design layout has been hallways that branch off from each other with rooms full of monsters added in. So far I've set up a dungeon generator based off this algorithm: http://www.roguebasin.com/index.php?title=Dungeon-Building_Algorithm. My first problem is that since my hallways aren't 1 space wide, they look often cut off from each other which is not the intended effect.

[image: You can see what I'm talking about here].

I've been thinking of maybe changing the generation so that it stores the tiles in an array-list so that it can use that to find how each passage should connect, I've also thought of trying a different algorithm, but I'm hesitant because it would feel wasteful to not to try and fix this one first. Any bit of advice is helpful since I'm relatively new to this!

Take Note: There must be a special room that the player spawns in and a Boss room. In terms of this I'm not sure how always be sure to connect these rooms together, maybe a final generation after everything else is done?

Comment: This sounds like a neat problem.  I might start by generating rooms (with a max width/height) such that you can have "columns and rows" of rooms... then generate halls between rooms in the same row and adjacent columns, or same column and adjacent rooms.

Comment: I like the idea of linking them all together like that, but I think if I understand you correctly that will lead to some pretty straight connections, where I was thinking of more twisting passages. I'll give it a try and see what effect it gives though, thanks for the advice @Gus

Comment: If you don't like straight connections, try a spline and then make the path adjust width to match the two exits.

Comment: I think that it is important to measure the path from starting position to boss room. Having it to be of assumed length will result in similar gameplay time and complexity regardless of the randomness. But that's little offtopic. I think that the best way to proceed is to use divide and conquer algorithm. First divide your all map into smaller sectors and then use function that will fill them up. Of course this function must be able to match number of defined exits on sector borders. Based on area it should cover it may yield different results: corridor for small area, room for medium, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the simpler (but not complete) solution would be to store some metada of each "room/feature" you have built. If you choose the wall at the end of a corridor as the placement for some new feature exclude "corridor" as a valid feature.

It won't solve every map incosistency and if you have two different kind of corridors (broader ones and narrower ones) you won't ever see a corrider getting broader or narrower but it is a simple fix and rather quick fix.

There are way better solutions of course, but I would need more details about the algorith. For what I can see in the link you sent what it does is to choose a wall tile as placement and put a feature behind that. Maybe when deciding placement you dont need to watch only at the wall tile the random choose but to the whole continuous wall around it:

1. Choose a random feature (a corridor by example to build)
2. Choose a random wall tile somewhere
3. From each feature you will know how big is its opening.
4. Compare if there are enough wall tiles down (or right) to tidily place its opening, if not, choose the wall up / right of the your original election and try again. You can hit the scenario where is not possible to do so, you can start all over from point 1 and try again.

That is just over the top of my head, of course there are other solutions. But it might be good enough to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

I thought of using pseudo random number generator such as, mersenne twister, to search for random directions and then create rooms from a central point. If there are no collisions, you can create a room there and then randomly pick another direction. As you build upon your central point, the result won't be a straight connection.